# Url rewrite question

Tags: asp.net

When you have done your url rewrite for a url what happens when you use your code behind file and use request.querystring when there aren't any cos you url has been re-written. I haven't implemented url re-writing yet and want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not sure if I understand your question...

If you use url rewriting the user sees on the browser a url like this one

```
www.yourdomain.com/category1/product1
```

While you see on the code behind something like this

```
www.yourdomain.com?cat=1&prod=1
```

The friendly url is converted to the "ulgy" format before reaching your page logic, so the querystring will be there and ready to be processed.